# What is this one-handed tool with five dull steel "blades" called?

Tags: equipment

[image]

I've been using it to break down clumpy powders, it's the best thing I have for the job by far, and I need to buy more for people helping me.

Comment: Have you tried using a sifter instead? Breaking down clumpy powders is the purpose of that tool.

Comment: I have a large mesh "bowl" for sifting. With a high fat coconut milk powder, the clumps are too solid to sift apart. They really need mashing. After mashing I sift, then mash the remaining clumps, then sift and mash one or two more times until it's all smooth :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's a [pastry blender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastry_blender), less commonly also called a pastry cutter or dough blender. The primary use is cutting (mixing) solid fat into flour to make pastry dough.

Another common variety has stiff wires instead of the metal strips yours has.

[image: pastry blender with wires]

That kind also works fine for pastry dough, but likely won't work as well for your alternative use on clumpy powders; it'll tend to flex out of the way a bit, especially if the clumps are hard.

Comment: I use the above pictured tool for smashing up avacados and mixing in the tomatoes, onions and lime juice when making guacamole. Works like a charm.

Comment: I always used wire pastry cutters (that's the term I learned), until one day one broke and burst apart like a spring, causing a mess and some cuts in the process. I don't know if it was faulty or just poorly constructed (it was a new one with a plastic handle, which replaced a wooden-handled one whose wires had gotten too deformed/floppy), but just something to keep in mind if deciding between wire and bladed.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I use a potato masher to mix guacamole.

Comment: @Chloe  -That works too!!